# A colorscale legend in d3 does not show the first Axis label tick

Tags: d3.js, legend, axis

I have a colorscale legend made with d3. My colorscale does not use any data for the legend size itself. It just split the color evenly over. My problem is that the first tick label of the axis is sometimes missing, and sometimes not. I can't seem to find the issue. See pictures 1,2 and 3.

[Picture of colorscale with data from 0 to 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22MS3.png)

[Picture of colorscale with data from 1 to 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaJfB.png)

[Picture of colorscale with data from 1 to 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2sMB.png)

This is my Scale;

```
var labels = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([(this.enableMathRounding ? minRoundValue : this.minValue), (this.enableMathRounding ? maxRoundValue : this.maxValue)])
  .range(this.reverseDirectionAxisNumbers ? [this.height, 0] : [0, this.height])
```

This is how I add it to the axis;

```
var axis = this.isHorizontal ? d3
    .axisBottom(labels)
    .ticks(this.numberOfTicks) : d3
      .axisLeft(labels)
      .ticks(this.numberOfTicks)
```

I have tried to use " .tickValues(labels.ticks().concat(labels.domain()[0])) ", but this results in a very tick first line.

When I look at the array it seems like it does not include the first number of the domain. And it seems like its random, but with somewhat consistency.

If I use " .tickValues([this.minValue, this.maxValue]) " it will always show the min and max value, but only 2 ticks. Generating all the ticks results in the same issue as before.

Thanks for help.